# XPath - select text of selected child nodes

Tags: xpath, html-agility-pack

Given that I have a following xml:

```html
<div id="Main">
    <div class="quote">
        This is a quote and I don't want this text
    </div> 
    <p>
        This is content.
    </p>
    <p>  
        This is also content and I want both of them
    </p>
</div>
```

Is there **"a XPath"** to help me select inner text of **div#Main** as a **single node**, but must exclude texts of any **div.quote**.

I just want the text: *"This is content.This is also content and I want both of them"*

Thanks in advance

Here is the code to test the XPath, I'm using .NET with HtmlAgilityPack but I believe the xPath should work with any languages

```cs
[Test]
public void TestSelectNode()
{
    // Arrange 
    var html = "<div id=\"Main\"><div class=\"quote\">This is a quote and I don't want this text</div><p>This is content.</p><p>This is also content and I want both of them</p></div>";
    var xPath = "//div/*[not(self::div and @class=\"quote\")]/text()";

    var doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(html);

    // Action
    var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(xPath);

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual("This is content.This is also content and I want both of them", node.InnerText);
}
```

The test was failed obviously because the xPath is still not correct.

```cs
Test 'XPathExperiments/TestSelectNode' failed:
    Expected values to be equal.

    Expected Value : "This is content.This is also content and I want both of them"
    Actual Value   : "This is content."
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is an XPath that will give you this as a single node, because the values you're trying to obtain *aren't* a single node.  Is there a reason you can't do this?

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
// Action
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xPath);
foreach(var node in nodes)
{
   sb.Append(node.InnerText);
}

// Assert
Assert.AreEqual("This is content.This is also content and I want both of them", 
                sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Thank mate, your solution is actually the way i'm using right now. I was just wondering whether xPath supports a magic way to get that data without writing these code. I saw xPath 2.0 support function concat but I cannot use it as .NET does not recognize the syntax.

Comment: The `concat()` function actually exists in XPath 1.0, but it can't be used to combine all the items from a single node-set. It concatenates a series of arguments, like `concat(node1, node2, 'hi', node3)`.  Not sure if 2.0 has something that can combine a node-set, though the `string-join()` function might do that.  Typically in .NET, evaluating a non-node selection XPath is done differently from selecting nodes.  For example `XPathNavigator` has `Select()` for selecting nodes, and `Evaluate()` for evaluating XPath in general.  Does HtmlAgilityPack have a method for evaluating general XPaths?

Answer (score 0):

You want the text of any child of the div who is not div with class quote:

```
div/*[not(self::div and @class="quote")]/text()
```

Comment: Thank mate, but this XPath selects only the text of first **p**. I want texts of all children of the main div. In other words, I want inner text of div#Main exclude texts of div with class "quote"

Comment: Selects both for me as well. ( using perl xpath ) What are you using to eval that xpath?

Comment: Well, perhaps the description is not clear enough. I want the XPath which I can select as a "single node" and the node contain the desired text. I'm using HtmlAgilityPack

Answer (score 0):

There's no XPath that would give you a combined string value, because XPath selects node objects and only node objects, even if they're text nodes.

Seeing as you have `<p>` nodes in the `<div>` in question, I'd use

```
div[@id='Main']/p/text()
```

which produces a list of text nodes in `<p>` elements in a `<div id="Main">`. Iterating through these and concatenating text contents should be simple.