# Inner text of Node ignoring inner text of children

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

Pardon me if it sounds too simple to be asked here but since this is my very first day with html-agility-pack, I am unable to sort out a way to select the inner text of a node which is the direct child of the node and ignoring inner text of the children nodes.

For example

```
<div id="div1">
   <div class="h1"> this needs to be selected
   <small> and not this</small>
   </div>
</div>
```

currently I am trying this

```
HtmlDocument page = new HtmlWeb().Load(url);
var s = page.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='div1']//div[@class='h1']");
string selText = s.innerText;
```

which returns the whole text (e.g- this needs to be selected and not this).
Any suggestions??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `/text()` option to get all text nodes directly under a specific tag. If you only need the first one, add `[1]` to it:

```
page.LoadHtml(text);
var s = page.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='div1']//div[@class='h1']/text()[1]");
string selText = s.InnerText;
```

Answer (score 3):

The `div` could possibly have multiple text nodes if there is text before and after its children.  As I similarly indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14624054/1945651), I think the best way to get all the direct text content of a node is to do something like:

```
HtmlDocument page = new HtmlWeb().Load(url);
var nodes = page.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='div1']//div[@class='h1']/text()");

StringBuilder sb  = new StringBuilder();
foreach(var node in nodes)
{
   sb.Append(node.InnerText);
}

string content = sb.ToString();
```